# ERROR:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(89) - Chartify

Tags: python, python-3.x, spotify, chartify

I'm trying the new library(Chartify) provided by Spotify Team. On running the code below, I'm receiving the following error:

```
import chartify
import pandas as pd
file = "./data/Social_Network_Ads.csv"
data = pd.read_csv(file, sep = ',')

chart = chartify.Chart(blank_labels=True, y_axis_type='categorical', x_axis_type='linear')
chart.plot.scatter(
        data_frame=data,
        categorical_columns='Gender',
        numeric_column='EstimatedSalary',
        color_column='EstimatedSalary')
chart.style.color_palette.reset_palette_order()

chart.set_title("Scatter Plot w.r.t. Salaries of different Gender")
chart.set_subtitle("Labels for specific observations.")
chart.show()


[9643:9643:1127/175201.738360:ERROR:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(89)] Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported. See https://crbug.com/638180.
```

The HTML is being created though, but on opening the HTML, It gives a blank page.

Answer (score 0):

An old question, but if you are facing similar issues... That message is related to the OS while executing X tool.

As a workaround, this helped me to solve the issue on a CentOS 7.7 while trying to execute different binaries!

```
export QTWEBENGINE_DISABLE_SANDBOX=1
```